# Checking if records exist prevents from saving after edit

Tags: c#, wpf

I have code which checks for an occurrence of data before you can insert it into to the database. My problem is that after editing my existing data from the database, it keeps on showing the message that it already exists. Can someone please help me with a solution that will prevent it from blocking my entry of data after editing? Here is my C# code below:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (txtFullNames.Text.Length == 0)
    {
    Errormessage.Text = "Please enter your fullname";
    txtFullNames.Focus();
    }
    else if(!Regex.IsMatch(txtFullNames.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z]"))
    {
    Errormessage.Text = "Fullname must not contain a number";
    }
    else if (txtSurname.Text.Length == 0)
    {
    Errormessage.Text = "Please enter your Surname";
    txtSurname.Focus();
    }
    else if (!Regex.IsMatch(txtSurname.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z]"))
    {
    Errormessage.Text = "Surname must not contain a number";
    }
    else if (txtEmail.Text.Length == 0)
    {
    Errormessage.Text = "Please enter your Email Address";
    txtEmail.Focus();
    }
    else if (!Regex.IsMatch(txtEmail.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-

zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$"))

    {
    Errormessage.Text = "Please enter you valid email address";
    txtEmail.Focus();
    }
    else if (cboGender.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
    Errormessage.Text = "Please select your Gender";
    cboGender.Focus();
    }
    else if (cboCompany.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
    Errormessage.Text = "Please select your Company";
    cboCompany.Focus();
    }
    else if (txtUserName.Text.Length == 0)
    {
    Errormessage.Text = "Please enter your Username";
    txtUserName.Focus();
    }
    else if (txtPassword.Password.Length == 0)
    {
    Errormessage.Text = "Please enter your password";
    txtPassword.Focus();
    }
    else if (txtConfirmPassword.Password.Length == 0)
    {
    Errormessage.Text = "Please confirm your password";
    txtConfirmPassword.Focus();
    }
    else if (txtPassword.Password != txtConfirmPassword.Password)
    {
    Errormessage.Text = "Both password must match";
    }
    else
    {
    SqlConnection oConnection = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand Check_Exist = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserName from UserEnrollment WHERE username = 

@UserName AND Password = @Password", oConnection);`enter code here`

    Check_Exist.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUserName.Text);
    Check_Exist.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Password);
    oConnection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = Check_Exist.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
    MessageBox.Show("Username and Password already exist!", "Error Message", 

MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxImage.Error);

    }
    else
    {
    int Gender = 0;
    bool passed = int.TryParse(cboGender.SelectedValue.ToString(), out Gender);
    int Company = 0;
    passed = int.TryParse(cboCompany.SelectedValue.ToString(), out Company);
    if (passed)
    {
    try
    {
    switch (g_i_commitType)
    {
    case 1:
    {
    bool _var = _da.InsertData(UserID,
    txtUserName.Text,
    txtPassword.Password,
    txtFullNames.Text,
    txtSurname.Text,
    txtEmail.Text,
    Gender,
    Company
    );
    } break;
    case 2:
    {
    bool _var = _da.EditData(UserId,
    txtUserName.Text,
    txtPassword.Password,
    txtFullNames.Text,
    txtSurname.Text,
    txtEmail.Text,
    Gender,
    Company
    );
    } break;
    }
    LoadGridUsers();
    MessageBox.Show("Data Successfully Submited", "Confirmation Message");
    DeleteTextBox();
    Errormessage.Text = "";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    MessageBox.Show("A handled exception occurred" + ex.Message, "Error Message", 

MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);

    }
    }
    }
```

I am not sure where my logic would prevent me from saving after editing.

Answer (score 0):

Put your "checking" code into if statement: `if(g_i_commitType == 1)` as it's your "adding" mode for the view and only for `g_i_commitType == 1` you should check whether a user already exists or not.

```
// all you validation if statements
else
{
    if(g_i_commitType == 1)
    {
        SqlConnection oConnection = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand Check_Exist = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserName from UserEnrollment WHERE username = @UserName AND Password = @Password", oConnection);`enter code here`

        Check_Exist.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUserName.Text);
        Check_Exist.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Password);
        oConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = Check_Exist.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username and Password already exist!", "Error Message", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            return;
        }
    }

    int Gender = 0;
    // rest of you code
```

Comment: Thanks i managed to fix my problem and i also tried yours and it works fine for me,